# Statistical test to compare Dirichlet distributions

Tags: statistical-significance, dirichlet-distribution

I want assess if two groups are statistically significantly different. I assume the data points in both groups are generated from a Dirichlet distribution - is there an appropriate test for this?

Each data point $i$ consists of $v_i = [p_0, p_1, .., p_k], \sum p_j=1$. I want to test if the Dirichlet parameters $[\alpha_0,\alpha_1,..,\alpha_k]$ generating these samples are different in the two groups. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you find any way to deal with this ? I would like to do the same but can't find a good way !
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ninou136 please don't ask questions or comment using *answers*. Answers are meant to answer the question.

Comment: @Ninou136 No I didn't! Sidelined the problem for the time being..